# Python : Why do we need a build tool, what will you suggest for CI?

Tags: python, django, build, continuous-integration, package

I have quite a bit experience in `Python`, but I haven't yet used any `Build tools` as such.

My technology :

- Python
- Django

> Python devs talks about Continues Integration which needs the following :

- VCS [ I use GIT ]
- **Build Tool [ I knowing nothing about ]**
- CI System like Jenkins [ I am learning ]

So, **Why use a `Build Tool` what does it provides** ?

Is it same as packaging tools ?

I heard of `maven` and `ant` but never heard any using them in the python world, why is that ?

What will you recommend for first timer with `Build tools` ?

How does that helps in deployment ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The wiki for [Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) pretty much explains it.

Build tools relate to what is necessary to build your entire project. If your project is 100% pure python then you probably don't have any build tools as its all interpreted scripts. You would keep committing to the project, and it would keep building (if building is neccessary), and testing.

Compiled languages (or if your python project needs to be packaged somehow to be tested) would require build tools to produce a program that can be run and be tested by the CI system.

If, for instance, your project were C++, you might be using `make` as your build tool. When you commit new code, `make` has to be run to build the project and be tested.

Comment: I got this much part from the `CI` docs, now what build tool for python and why ?

Comment: Python doesn't need build tools unless you are using extensions that need to be compiled. Nothing to build.

Comment: How will the dependencies be handled ?

Comment: I suppose the closest thing to a build tool could be a dist util. Like virtual env and pip, or building into an egg using distutils, or packaging it with something like pyinstaller. It would be more like packing really. I guess the entire concept is just about putting your component together by whatever means you need, so that it can be integrated into the system

Comment: Okay ... but I have heard people using `buildout` what is that for ?

Comment: buildout seems like a virtualenv lookalike which requires additional configuration files without providing additional value (I just watched the intro video half way through). It's probably more powerful, but virtualenv provides everything I ever needed (using nose for testing) while sticking to standards. Everything you can do in virtualenv, you can do in a full Python installation.

Comment: as per the buildout documentation it is a good tool when you want to build a library not an application.

Comment: Virtualenv and a pip requirements.txt have worked for my needs. Buildout would be for those advanced situations where you need recipes to locally build the dependencies.

Comment: By build tool, do you mean something like Gulp or Brunch? (http://brunch.io/) The purpose there would be to minify JS and CSS, and compress images. Django has some options (http://owaislone.org/blog/modern-frontends-with-django/) and there is a tutorial here: https://lincolnloop.com/blog/integrating-front-end-tools-your-django-project/

Comment: @Josh, "build tools" would just be anything that can be configured to run a recipe for assembling what is in your source repo into a runnable end product. This could mean performing actions on front end stuff like css or js. It could mean compiling cpython extension modules. Or maybe it needs to do something like codegen. Another example would be if you want to generate documentation.